# Cannot find module '@angular/core' after installing angular2-database

Tags: node.js, angular

I am developing an Angular 2 web app in VS2015. after downloading angular2-database with npm I have noticed that I get 6 errors. In particular the files BootstrapPaginator.d.ts, DataTable.d.ts and paginator.d.ts cannot find the module @angular/core. What is that?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the library? I can't find it in NPM... Thanks!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable

Comment: try ```npm install -S @angular/core```

Comment: yes, now it works!